# D: split string by comma, but not quoted string

Tags: regex, string, d

I need to split string by comma, that not quoted like:
`foo, bar, "hello, user", baz`

to get:

```
foo
bar
hello, user
baz
```

Comment: Please don't post a question for the sake of getting a badge/hat - you've answered your own question within a minute of posting it, you obviously knew the answer before you asked it.

Comment: I would suggest to use [`std.csv`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_csv.html), but I cannot get it to work as expected.

Comment: There is a sample here how to [parse a CSV string](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_csv.html).

Comment: @IStanley, Actually, SO has functionality to write both, question and answer, at the same time.

Comment: @sigod : doesn't change the fact that it was abuse of the system. It's hardly an original or interesting question that hasn't been covered before that would merit independent documentation. Interesting to know though - I can't imagine there are many cases where it would be used validly...

Comment: @IStanley, SO can handle it. Like in this case. P.S. I've used it once.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer It specifically says you are encouraged to answer your own question, including as you post so it can be searched by others later.

Comment: How is the JavaScript thread relevant to this? Yes, it is the same problem, but it is clearly asking for JS solution! Also, it is pretty much possible, and common to ask a question, and once the research is done, come up with an answer, if nobody gave a good answer already... I've done that few times.

Comment: @DejanLekic - good point, I've removed my duplicate flag. I didn't spot the 'd' tag, and assumed the thing in the title was supposed to be a sad face... I'd be surprised if there isn't a duplicate for this, but don't have time to look again...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`std.csv`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_csv.html):

```
import std.csv;
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    auto str = `foo,bar,"hello, user",baz`;

    foreach (row; csvReader(str))
    {
        writeln(row);
    }
}
```

Application output:

```
["foo", "bar", "hello, user", "baz"]
```

Note that I modified your CSV example data. As `std.csv` wouldn't correctly parse it, because of space () before first quote (`"`).

Comment: I wonder whether that is desirable... IMHO, if there is a space after comma, it should be part of the parsed field: `foo, "hello"` becomes `["foo", " hello"]` (added the space to the second field). Additionally, parser should be parametrized to ignore such spaces if needed (basically automatic trim on both sides). Sure this should happen only if the field is string, naturally...

Comment: If the field is quoted at all, the whole thing is supposed to be quoted. If the field doesn't start with a quote, a quote (nor comma, nor newline) is not supposed to appear in the field at all. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180 The real question though is what does Excel and google docs do? Google doc seems to ignore leading spaces in a csv field, regardless of quotes. I can try excel later... BTW my csv.d reads the leading space into the data (leading spaces are not supposed to be ignored)

Comment: I've seen that RFC many times, and all I can say is that it has been done by someone who either ignored real-life CSV scenarios, or had limited experience with CSV in the past (probably with some spreadsheet support for CSV files). I can guarantee that people will have leading or trailing spaces in their fields, even when they are quoted.

Comment: Aye, that's why I was comparing against Excel and gdocs since that's what people actually do with csvs in the real world. My csv.d accepts leading spaces... but every time I actually use them, I tend to strip the fields anyway before trying to do anything else, which is consistent with Google docs too.

Comment: @user1432751, something like this: `writeln(csvReader(str).front);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use next snippet to complete this task:

```
File fileContent;
string fileFullName = `D:\code\test\example.csv`;
fileContent = File (fileFullName, "r");

auto r = regex(`(?!\B"[^"]*),(?![^"]*"\B)`); 
foreach(line;fileContent.byLine)
  {
   auto result = split(line, r);
   writeln(result);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are parsing a specific file format, splitting by line and using regex often isn't correct, though it will work in many cases. I prefer to read it in character by character and keep a few flags for state (or use someone else's function where appropriate that does it for you for this format). D has std.csv: http://dlang.org/phobos/std_csv.html or my old old csv.d which is minimal but basically works too: https://github.com/adamdruppe/arsd/blob/master/csv.d (haha 5 years ago was my last change to it, but hey, it still works)

Similarly, you can kinda sorta "parse" html with regex... sometimes, but it breaks pretty quickly outside of simple cases and you are better off using an actual html parser (which probably is written to read char by char!)

Back to quoted commas, reading csv, for example, has a few rules with quoted content: first, of course, commas can appear inside quotes without going to the next field. Second, newlines can also appear inside quotes without going to the next row! Third, two quote characters in a row is an escaped quote that is in the content, not a closing quote.

```
foo,bar
"this item has
two lines, a comma, and a "" mark!",this is just bar
```

I'm not sure how to read that with regex (eyeballing, I'm pretty sure yours gets the escaped quote wrong at least), but it isn't too hard to do when reading one character at a time (my little csv reader is about fifty lines, doing it by hand). Splitting the lines ahead of time also complicates compared to just reading the characters because you might then have to recombine lines later when you find one ends with a closing quote! And then your beautiful `byLine` loop suddenly isn't so beautiful.

Besides, when looking back later, I find simple character readers and named functions to be more understandable than a regex anyway.

So, your answer is correct for the limited scope you asked about, but might be missing the big picture of other cases in the file format you are actually trying to read.

edit: one last thing I want to pontificate on, these corner cases in CSV are an example of why people often say "don't reinvent the wheel". It isn't that they are really hard to handle - look at my csv.d code, it is short, pretty simple, and works at everything I've thrown at it - but that's the rub, isn't it? "Everything I've thrown at it". To handle a file format, you need to be aware of what the corner cases are so you can handle them, at least if you want it to be generic and take arbitrary user input. Knowing these edge cases tends to come more from real world experience than just taking a quick glance. Once you know them though, writing the code again isn't terribly hard, you know what to test for! But if you don't know it, you can write beautiful code with hundreds of unittests... but miss the real world case your user just happens to try that one time it matters.